# how to traverse a directory tree in python and those files which have extension of .py or .txt add them in a zipfile.?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to solve this problem but my code is zipping my whole home directory.[image]

here is my code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import zipfile


def main():
    newzipfile=zipfile.ZipFile("usama.zip","a")
    for folders,subfolders,files in os.walk("/home/amasu/"):

        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(".txt") or file.endswith(".py"):
                newzipfile.write(str(folders+"/"+file))




if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: What's your actual issue?

Comment: my issue is that i am unable to add just only files which have .txt and .py extensions when i try to add those files are adding into zipfile with thier directories.

Answer (score 0):

It worked on my machine when I replaced:

```
newzipfile.write(str(folders+"/"+file))
```

with:

```
newzipfile.write(folders + "/" + file, arcname=file)
```

The second parameter renames it, so that its path does not have directory delimiters anymore. This makes it so that only the file is written, instead of the whole path. In your current case, if you look inside the unzipped home directory at the actual files, the files should be only .py or .txt.

Also, not sure if this is relevant since you got actual files to zip, but you might want to close the newzipfile before your code exits:

```
newzipfile.close()
```